# User name and Login With AsyncTask

Tags: java, php, android, android-asynctask

I recently followed a guide on how to handle a username and login using php and MySQL. Unfortunately the guide doesn't cover AsyncTasks which are necessary now because android won't allow me to do any of the network stuff on the mainthread. ([This is the guide](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/))

I used the following code. (Crated an AsyncTask at the bottom and moved the contents of the OnClick Listener for the login button and moved it to the AsyncTask and made the button execute the asynctask. I am new to AsyncTask so there may be multiple issues. If you need more info pleas let me know.

```
Error: 01-22 10:25:13.140    3774-3788/com.Ayman.jokeit E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
    Process: com.Ayman.jokeit, PID: 3774
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.Ayman.jokeit.LoginActivity$LoginTask.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:81)
            at com.Ayman.jokeit.LoginActivity$LoginTask.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:70)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

I'm including the following relevant code:

```
package com.Ayman.jokeit;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.Ayman.jokeit.library.DatabaseHandler;
import com.Ayman.jokeit.library.UserFunctions;

public class LoginActivity extends Activity {
    Button btnLogin;
    Button btnLinkToRegister;
    EditText inputEmail;
    EditText inputPassword;
    TextView loginErrorMsg;

    // JSON Response node names
    private static String KEY_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static String KEY_ERROR = "error";
    private static String KEY_ERROR_MSG = "error_msg";
    private static String KEY_UID = "uid";
    private static String KEY_NAME = "name";
    private static String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
    private static String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);

        // Importing all assets like buttons, text fields
        inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginEmail);
        inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginPassword);
        btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
        btnLinkToRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLinkToRegisterScreen);
        loginErrorMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.login_error);

        // Login button Click Event
        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                //if you want to keep the loader from Ravi

                //and then, you add the AsyncTask
                LoginTask AsyncLogin = new LoginTask();
                AsyncLogin.execute();
            }

        });

        // Link to Register Screen
        btnLinkToRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        RegisterActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
    public class LoginTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... strings) {
            String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
            String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();
            UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
            JSONObject json = userFunction.loginUser(email, password);

            // check for login response
            try {
                if  (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
                    loginErrorMsg.setText("");
                    String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);
                    if(Integer.parseInt(res) == 1){
                        // user successfully logged in
                        // Store user details in SQLite Database
                        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
                        JSONObject json_user = json.getJSONObject("user");

                        // Clear all previous data in database
                        userFunction.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                        db.addUser(json_user.getString(KEY_NAME), json_user.getString(KEY_EMAIL), json.getString(KEY_UID), json_user.getString(KEY_CREATED_AT));

                        // Launch Dashboard Screen
                        Intent dashboard = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DashboardActivity.class);

                        // Close all views before launching Dashboard
                        dashboard.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(dashboard);

                        // Close Login Screen
                        finish();
                    }else{
                        // Error in login
                        loginErrorMsg.setText("Incorrect username/password");
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which is your line 81 from LoginActivity.java?

Comment: @NKN if  (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {

Comment: then probably json is null...
(so probably the code of userFunction.loginUser(email, password) is more relevant here...)

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is something wrong in loginUser method of UserFunctions class. I believe your android code could not reach your php server. You need to check if your php server is up&running(Assuming you built one). Can you reach yourIp/ah_login_api/login/ ? Is it possible that you missed to change ip in UserFunctions.java?